# Make div element adhere to top one

Tags: html, css

I want my options class div to adhere to my registraion class div in the same way that my registration class div adheres to the main-heading class div. For some reason the options class div floats way below the registration class div. Can someone provide a responsive solution to this? 
An explanation of why my options div doesn't show directly below my registration class div would be much obliged.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}

[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: right;

}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.row {
    height: 100%;
    border-color: red;
}

.footer {
    height: 25%;
}

.top-space {
    height: 25%;
}

.middle {
    height:150%;
}

.left-aside {
    height: 100%;
}

.main {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.right-aside {
    height: 100%;
}

.main-heading {
    height: 3%;
    margin: 0;
}

.registration {
    height: 60%;
    margin: 0;
}

.options {
    height: 50%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/indexController.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="header">
        <span><a href="#">Login</a> | <a href="#">Countries</a></span>
    </div>

    <div class="row top-space">
        <div class="col-3" style="height: 100%">
        </div>
        <div class="col-9" style="height: 100%">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row middle">
        <div class="col-3 left-aside">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 main">
            <div class="row main-heading">
                <div class="col-2">
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row registration">
                <div class="col-6 registration">
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 registration">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row options">
                <div class="col-12 options">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 right-aside">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row footer">
        <div class="col-3" style="height: 100%">
        </div>
        <div class="col-3" style="height: 100%">
        </div>
        <div class="col-3" style="height: 100%">
        </div>
        <div class="col-3" style="height: 100%">
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you clarify the problem a bit better? How do you mean 'adhere'?

Comment: Stick to the top one with no border.

Answer (score 1):

It happens like this because of your class `registration` is used two times, on the parent and the children, so that means the children will take `60%` of that `60%`. So give the children another class with 100% height

```
.registration-item {
  height: 100;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}

[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: right;

}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.row {
    height: 100%;
    border-color: red;
}

.footer {
    height: 25%;
}

.top-space {
    height: 25%;
}

.middle {
    height:150%;
}

.left-aside {
    height: 100%;
}

.main {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.right-aside {
    height: 100%;
}

.main-heading {
    height: 3%;
    margin: 0;
}

.registration {
    height: 60%;
    margin: 0;
}

.options {
    height: 50%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/indexController.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="header">
        <span><a href="#">Login</a> | <a href="#">Countries</a></span>
    </div>

    <div class="row top-space">
        <div class="col-3" style="height: 100%">
        </div>
        <div class="col-9" style="height: 100%">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row middle">
        <div class="col-3 left-aside">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 main">
            <div class="row main-heading">
                <div class="col-2">
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row registration" style="background-color: deeppink;">
                <div class="col-6 registration" style="background-color: deepskyblue;">
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 registration">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row options">
                <div class="col-12 options" style="background-color: deepskyblue;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 right-aside">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row footer">
        <div class="col-3" style="height: 100%">
        </div>
        <div class="col-3" style="height: 100%">
        </div>
        <div class="col-3" style="height: 100%">
        </div>
        <div class="col-3" style="height: 100%">
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The same can be said for `.options`.